# Should I separate the presentation layer from the application layer in React?

Tags: reactjs, architecture

If `React` is just the V of the MVC, how the React projects separate the **presentation layer**, such as display a name, from the **application tier**, such as fetch a user from a back-end API?

Many React tutorials mix the logic of **fetching data** with the logic of **displaying data**.

Is this a problem or a solution? What is the correct way to structure projects with React?

Answer (score 2):

Most **Tutorials**  aims at explaining concepts. Along with this some of them follow patterns and best practices some of them not it solely depends on the developer and use case scenarios.

You can use different **patterns** of reactjs. 
You can build actual UI using `Presentational Component or Functional or Stateless Component` and should make call to api service from `StateFull or Container Component or Smart Component`.
You can use redux to store this data. Call `actions` and `connect` to `store` in `smart Component` and pass data to `Presentation Component`;

I don't say this is the best practice but I feel convenient so I follow this
For example (without redux)

```
class Dashboard extends Component { //Smart or Container Component
    state = {dashboard:{}}

    async componentWillMount() {
        try {
            const response = await apiService.fetchDashboardInfo()
            this.setState({dashboard:response.data.data});
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("fetch dashboard info",error)
        }
    }

    render() {
        if(Object.keys(this.state.dashboard).length > 0) {
            return <DashboardDetail dashboard={this.state.dashboard}/>
        }
        return (
            <div>
                Loading
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const DashboardDetail = (props) =>{ //Stateless Component
    return(
        <div className="main-content">
            <div className="main-content-inner">
                <Field color={'red'} field={"Votes"} value={props.dashboard.total_vote} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const Field = (props) => { //Another Stateless Component
    return(
            <div className="infobox-data">
                <div className="infobox-content">{props.field}</div>
            </div>
    )
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: Your example looks good.
But since I started studying **architectural patterns**, like MVC, I don't feel good about `View` acting as `Controller`.
I believe that separating responsibilities is a good way to increase project quality and productivity.

Comment: I don't understand where is `View` acting as `Controller`? If you submit button press or any other actions you call particular `controller` (Make REST API call with the particular `route` or `controller` )  which perform necessary action on `M`

Comment: Basically, View displays the data, Model stores the data, Controller fetch the data. Right?

Comment: Right. React (V) display data. User interacts with V make an action which calls Controller which fetch data and return back to V.

Comment: I believe that views shouldn't know about controllers that control them.
Can views call controllers directly and proactively? Isn't a anti-pattern?